# How do I get around access denied when trying to view the parent of an IFRAME

Tags: javascript, iframe, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

So I have this craptastic code that I inherited and an insane client as well.  This program uses IFRAMES to emulate AJAX like calls since the previous dev could not be bothered to just do AJAX.  Anyway, the problem is, is that the app calls a javascript that then sets the source of the IFRAME to some dynamic javascript.

Okay, now at the end of this javascipt, the IFRAME tries to set a value on the parent.  But in IE7 and IE8 I get "Permission Denied" errors when trying to access parent.document.  I imagine that this is to protect against cross domain security issues, however the parent and the child are in the same domain.  The site is all https; I don't know if this makes a difference.  Any ideas would be awesome.

Comment: Okay, so this only happens in IE7...  And intermittently.

Comment: What is the the dynamic javascript doing that is set to run in the `iframe`?

Comment: Or maybe AJAX was not being readily supported by the browser versions of the time, in turn having to rely on iFrames and emulations of iFrames to get the job done. Doesn't mean the code is craptastic, just means you are too new to the development arena to know how to interpret his code.

Answer (score 1):

Both the parent and the child need to be on the same domain **and** subdomain. Additionally, if whatever code runs in the`iframe` redirects the frame, it would no longer be in the correct domain when it is finished executing.